# Are "physical communities" different from "local communities"? Do we need disambiguation of terms perhaps?

Tags: discussion, tags

I like this question: [How to organize a solution to a problem in my local community?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/how-to-organize-a-solution-to-a-problem-in-my-local-community)

I'd love to see us talk more about local community and neighborhood organizing.

In this case the questioner is specifically asking about a neighborhood, which seems different from just a "physical community" as stated in the tag definition.

Do we need different tags for these cases?  I could see some blending, however.  For example: in the case of the homeowners association related questions, these are definitely both a neighborhood and a physical community.

Is talking about organizing at your city council or your local government similar or different?

Comment: Do you like "local communities" or do you have another tag name in mind?

Comment: Maybe physical communities ahold be called "in-person communities, with "person to person face time" being the distinguishing feature.

Comment: This would give more space for "local communities" which relates to geographic boundaries such as neighborhoods or civic boundaries

Comment: And yes there would at least occasionally be overlap.

Answer (score 7):

I can see a distinction between "local communities" and "physical communities". In my eyes, we've had a few of both types of questions recently.

#### Recent Local Communities Questions

- [How to organize a solution to a problem in my local community?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/how-to-organize-a-solution-to-a-problem-in-my-local-community)
- [Would a community kitchen be accepted in America?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/would-a-community-kitchen-be-accepted-in-america)
- [How to motivate villagers to monitor well water levels of their wells?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-motivate-villagers-to-monitor-well-water-levels-of-their-wells)

All three of these are relevant to the locality of the situation. They are "real world" questions and impact a local area and are related to "where someone lives".

#### Recent Physical Communities Questions

- [How should I organize a Meetup group to generate sales leads?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/how-should-i-organize-a-meetup-group-to-generate-sales-leads)
- ["But I posted it on Facebook!" How do I get my community to use broader communication channels?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/but-i-posted-it-on-facebook-how-do-i-get-my-community-to-use-broader-communic)
- [I broke the Christmas tradition!](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/i-broke-the-christmas-tradition)

These questions are "real world" too, but the "where someone lives" aspect isn't the guiding factor in the question.

---

I'm trying to work out a better way to define the difference between the two than "where someone lives" is the relevant factor. We can do that.

I agree that an additional tag would work well. I don't think we need to split [physical-communities](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-communities). I think a new one would work to keep these organized appropriately.

Comment: I agree with this.  I think the key difference is if it is a community you are part of "by choice" (ie, you can easily leave), or a community you are part of by nature (ie, where you live, though there are probably some other examples, such as court ordered counseling or prisons or the like.)  There is really a third category of groups where it is moderately difficult to leave, but easier than the second category.  Jobs would be an example of something that falls in to the third category as you can leave them easily enough, but it isn't as trivial as leaving a club.